# C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails.

Error
`-bash: /mnt/c/Ruby30-x64/bin/rails: C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

I'm trying to run server on my machine but it is showing this error. I have been working on this for quite sometime, everything was working fine. Just switched to another project and then came back here, this error showed up. Please help.

Working on WSL in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It was a ruby version error. The ruby version wasn't set.

This helped me resolve the issue `rvm use {ruby_version}@{project}`

eg: `rvm use 2.6.6@eloecommerce`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the path and alias to ~/.bashrc

```
export RUBYBIN=/{{YOUR_PATH}}/Ruby30-x64/bin
alias ruby="$RUBYBIN"/ruby
alias ruby.exe=$RUBYBIN/ruby.exe
alias gem="$RUBYBIN"/gem.cmd
alias bundle="$RUBYBIN"/bundle.bat
alias bundler="$RUBYBIN/bundler.bat"
alias jekyll="$RUBYBIN/jekyll.bat"
```